# Function L in Yellow Paper

Tags: yellow-paper

Is L used as a generic function in the yellow paper or does it represent something specific? The subparts are quite specific but not L as a whole. What does a collapse function mean?
Also, what does this line mean -

> It shall be understood that σ[a]s is not a ‘physical’
> member of the account and does not contribute to its later
> serialization.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This may or may not help: https://github.com/benjaminion/YellowPaper_CheatSheet/blob/master/YPCheatSheet.pdf